# Maven plugin to concat and minify javascript

Tags: maven, minify

I have 100s of javascript files inside the hierarchy of folders and I want two sets of output. one is to have a concatenated version for debugging purposes and the other one is to have a concat + minfy version. I am currently using the below plugin but in this I need to provide each and every file that I need to minify. I am looking for a plugin which needs only parent folder and satisfy the above conditions.

```
<groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
```

Comment: The Minify plugin is based on YUI compressor, and they are both buggy and break with the latest CSS standards. See e.g. https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin/issues/161 . See my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52229690/421049 to try to find a non-buggy alternative.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should take a look to [yui compression maven plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/index.html) which sounds like the thing you need.

Comment: Yes, I was using it but not correctly. I was missing the aggregation of resources.

Comment: YUI Compressor is completely broken with CSS3. See e.g. https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/268 and https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/313 .

Answer (score 33):

[YUI compression maven plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/) worked for me.
I will show what all I did to make it work.

> - To concatenate all the js files I used aggregation.

Details of the elements used.

> - **preProcessAggregates** - To process aggregation before minification.
> - **aggregations** - To aggregate the multiple resources in folder hierarchy to a single file.
> - **aggregation** - There can be multiple aggregation elements inside parent aggregations.
> - **insertNewLine** - Insert newline after each file eof, while concatenation/aggregation of files.
> - **inputDir** - Parent directory inside which files would be searched for concatenation/aggregation.
> - **sourceDirectory** - Directory under which files would be searched for minification.
> - **outputDirectory** - Directory under which minified output would be placed.
> - **nosuffix** - If set to true, then plugin will not add '-min' to the minified file.

There are 2 types of `<exclude>` property:-

> - First is part of aggregation, which basically excludes files from aggregation.
> - Second is part of the plugin to exclude files from minification.

Plugin code:-

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <preProcessAggregates>true</preProcessAggregates>
    <aggregations>
      <aggregation>
        <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
        <output>${basedir}/target/single.js</output>
        <inputDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/js</inputDir>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.js</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*abc.js</exclude>
          <exclude>**/compressed.css</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </aggregation>
    </aggregations>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*-min.js</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*-min.css</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <jswarn>false</jswarn>
    <nosuffix>false</nosuffix>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/target</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>compress_js_css</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compress</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Alternatively, the plugin can be found here: http://davidb.github.io/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/

Comment: why did @Mady set nosuffix to false? normally you only care about deploying the minified version right? http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: YUI Compressor is completely broken with CSS3. See e.g. https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/268 and https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/313 .

Answer (score 4):

Mady, Minify Maven Plugin does also support include/exclude patterns.
Please take a look at the [Lexicographical ordering](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/examples/patterns.html) example page from the plugin documentation.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, yeah it works well, but closure jsEngine is not able to minify, it is breaking at some point. Initially, I was inclined to closure that's why i used the minify-maven-plugin.