# Maven YUI Compressor, concat but don't minify (turn compression off)

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, yui, vaadin7

I am working on a legacy project, it's a Vaadin component which uses Maven YUI plugin to minify and concatenate the javascript files. There are 40 js files.

The YUI plugin works as it should, minifying the 40 js files and concatenating them into one file (which is then referenced with `@javascript` in Vaadin).

Because of the minification development for new features is painful, but I can't remove the YUI plugin because then I'd need to add a `@javascript` annotation for all 40 js files.

Is there a way to make YUI aggregate but **not** minify. I had read the docs and tried changing the goals (i.e. to jslint only) but it seems I can't aggregate if I don't use the `compress` goal.

Am I missing something here?

Here's my YUI config as it stands:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jslint</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jslint</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.js</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/VAADIN/js/*.js</exclude>
        <exclude>**/depends/*.js</exclude>
      </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  <execution>
  <id>minify</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>compress</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
  <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
  <force>true</force>       
  <excludeWarSourceDirectory>true</excludeWarSourceDirectory>
  <linebreakpos>-1</linebreakpos>
  <aggregations>
    <aggregation>
      <inputDir>target/classes/[path]/components</inputDir>
      <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
      <output>${project.build.directory}/classes/[path].js</output>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.js</include>
      <include>**/Copyright.txt</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/depends/d3_3.4.6.js</exclude>
    </excludes>
    </aggregation>
  </aggregations>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*.js</include>
    <include>**/[project.name].css</include>
  </includes>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/depends/*.js</exclude>
  </excludes>
  </configuration>
  </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

**N.b.** I've also tried the above with the aggregation config in the jslint goal with no joy.

There must be a way to stop the compression (I know YUI is a compression plugin, but it has other functions (such as lint) so I'd assume you can turn compression off). Also, Vaadin's `@javascript` annotation takes a comma separated list of js files. I feel adding 40 would be way too much, but maybe there is a way for `@javascript` to take a directory. (docs don't mention this though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decided to anwers this one I found a solution, party for anyone finding it and partly because it didnt get any other answers.

The solution was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747319/maven-plugin-to-concat-and-minify-javascript) by someone asking the opersite of what I needed. @Mady pointed out the different includes/excludes in the plugin config

Short story long, you can exclude ALL .js files in the minifyer **but** included them in the agreegator:

```
<execution>
  <id>minify</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>compress</goal>
  </goals>                      
  <configuration>
    <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
    <force>true</force>
    <excludeWarSourceDirectory>true</excludeWarSourceDirectory>
    <linebreakpos>-1</linebreakpos>
    <aggregations>
      <aggregation>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.js</include> <!-- INCLUDES FOR CONCATENATION -->
        </includes>
      </aggregation>
    </aggregations>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.js</exclude> <!-- EXCLUDE ALL JS FROM MINIFICATION -->
    </excludes> 
  </configuration>
</execution>
```