# CSS minifier for Maven compatible with modern CSS

Tags: css, maven, minify

Can someone point me to a Maven dependency I can add to my POM to minify a file using modern CSS?

Before you say to use `com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin`, note that it breaks calculated values: https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin/issues/161

In fact any CSS minifier based on YUI Compressor will break calculated values: https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/268

And `com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin`/YUI corrupts the file if it contains certain sequences such as the end of a comment `*/*…` (such as found in minified Bootstrap Reboot): https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/313 .

So is there no CSS minifier for Maven that works with modern CSS?

Comment: I know, this is not an answer, but simple do not do it.
CSS minification have no much sense anymore.

The main goal of the process is to reduce amount of data which browser need to download, and amount of connection which browser need to do with HTTP-server.

But combination of GZIP + HTTP/2, which any modern browser support, naturally provides the same effect.

In fact, in actual situation, CSS minification give extremely small benefit.